# Reset jQuery ui date Picker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

When the user click on the **Reset** button, it clears the input box but it does NOT reset to today's date. Instead it disable the date range, which I do not want.  How do do I get it so that all the dates show up again? Just like in the beginning.

I tried doing this.  Clear the data and then refresh it but it still doesn't work.
$( "#to").datepicker('setDate', null);
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "refresh" );

Here's my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/seX4mgOGAeKDZRGTJCWx?p=preview

OR

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
       numberOfMonths: 2,
       minDate: 0,
       onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
       }
    });

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
       numberOfMonths: 2,
       onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
       }
    });
});

function clearData(){
   $( "#to").datepicker('setDate', null);
   $( "#from").datepicker('setDate', null);
   $( "#to" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
   $( "#from" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Departure <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
Arrival <input type="text" id="to" name="to"><br><br> 

<button type="button" onclick="clearData()">Reset</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

call jQuery change method on form and to date Id attributes.
$( "#to" ).change();
 $( "#from" ).change();